# Why is there no Dispose method to override in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, dispose

I am trying to dispose of my DbContext in my GenericRep from my Generic Service.

My generic repo is implementing the pattern described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

I have set up the first part in my repo:

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T>, IDisposable
    where T: BaseEntity
{
    protected readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    protected DbSet<T> _dbSet;
    .
    .
    .
    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
```

Now in the article they have this in the StudentController:

```
  protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
     studentRepository.Dispose();
     base.Dispose(disposing);
  }
```

They don't have StudentController implementing IDisposable or anything.
They just seem to be able to override Dispose as a standard overridable method on Object I guess.

So I need to put this in my Generic Service.

Here is my Generic Service:

```
public class GenericService<T> : IGenericService<T>
    where T : BaseEntity
{
    private IGenericRepository<T> _genericRepo;

    public GenericService(IGenericRepository<T> genericRepo)
    {
        _genericRepo = genericRepo;
    }
    . 
    .
    .
    public override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _genericRepo.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

So I have two red squigglies on my code.

1) No suitable method found to override for GenericService.

Is this a standard overridable object in Full Framework but not .Net Core?

2) Object does not contain a definition for Dispose on base.Dispose call.

Is this just done differently somehow in .Net Core?

**UPDATE 1:**

Thanks Nkosi for your answer below (Answer 1).

So now I am calling the serviceRepo dispose from my controller like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CasesController : Controller, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IGenericService<Case> _caseGenericService;

    public CasesController(IGenericService<Case> caseGenericService)
    {
        _caseGenericService = caseGenericService;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _caseGenericService.Dispose();
                base.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
```

It kind of works, for a few disposes.
But then it seems to start hanging.

Comment: There is no `Dispose()` on `System.Object`. They're inheriting from `Controller`, which does have that method.

Comment: `Controller` already inherits from `IDisposable`.  remove the `Dispose()` method and update the `Dispose(bool disposing)` to `override`.

Comment: Take a look at the source code for [Controller](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/44048331e936de39073ca5eab97bd5b5cdb0a0f2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Controller.cs#L361) on github. you may need to make some modifications to how you are disposing of your controller.

Comment: Take a look at this [article here](https://andrewlock.net/four-ways-to-dispose-idisposables-in-asp-net-core/). I think you are overengineering your way through disposables by chaining together dispose methods. If you are using the dotnetcore DI framework it should do the right thing for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic service will have to define/implement disposable just like in the generic repository. There is nothing to override or base to call as the current class is defining it.

```
public class GenericService<T> : IGenericService<T>, IDisposable
    where T : BaseEntity
{
    private IGenericRepository<T> _genericRepo;

    public GenericService(IGenericRepository<T> genericRepo)
    {
        _genericRepo = genericRepo;
    }
    . 
    .
    .
    private bool disposed = false;
    // Protected implementation of Dispose pattern.
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed)
            return; 

        if (disposing) {
            _genericRepo.Dispose();
            // Free any other managed objects here.
            //
        }

        // Free any unmanaged objects here.
        //
        disposed = true;
    }    

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Reference [Implementing a Dispose Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx)