# Why derive from ControllerBase vs Controller for ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am following this tutorial for creating an ASP.NET Core Web API, and in the section on adding a controller, the tutorial gives code to replace the template code for a controller. One of the things that really caught my eye was that in the template code, I get:

```
TodoController : Controller
```

Then in the tutorial code I'm supposed to use instead of that, I find:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
TodoController : ControllerBase
```

I'm very interested to know why it is necessary to derive from `ControllerBase` instead of `Controller` for a Web API controller. Why is this done?

Comment: Note that you can make a controller that doesn't derive from anything, at least it works in .net 5+, I don't know about earlier versions

Answer (score 188, accepted):

> why it is necessary to derive from `ControllerBase` instead of `Controller` for a Web API controller.

It is not strictly necessary, just more to the point. The `Controller` class derives from `ControllerBase` and only adds some members that are needed to support Views.

Basically:

```
public abstract class Controller : ControllerBase
{
    public dynamic ViewBag { get; }
    public virtual ViewResult View(object model) { }
    // more View support stuff
}
```

When you write an API then ControllerBase matches your requirements better but both will work.

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/):

> Don't create a web API controller by deriving from the Controller class. Controller derives from ControllerBase and adds support for views, so it's for handling web pages, not web API requests. There's an exception to this rule: **if you plan to use the same controller for both views and web APIs, derive it from Controller**.

I seem to remember that there was no ControllerBase in the first MVC iterations, it was inserted later. Hence the slightly odd naming/inheritance structure.

Comment: As the ControllerBase class' summary puts it: ControllerBase - "A base class for an MVC controller without view support."

Answer (score 28):

FROM https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Don't create a web API controller by deriving from the Controller class. Controller derives from ControllerBase and adds support for views, so it's for handling web pages, not web API requests.

Comment: Unless you're using the same controller for both API requests and Views.  From your link:
"There's an exception to this rule: if you plan to use the same controller for both views and web APIs, derive it from Controller."

Answer (score -2):

One other important difference is that ControllerBase is abstract class that's why it doesn't implement Dispose method. So you need to handle yourself. see this [SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43294927/why-is-there-no-dispose-method-to-override-in-net-core)

Comment: I'm curious to understand how this is an attempt to answer the question?

Comment: @JimAho because it is another reason why it is inheriting from Controllerbase instead controller. in the linked entry explaining well.

Comment: Would probably be better to leave it as a comment then instead on [this already-popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55239483/2874896)

Answer (score -4):

when you change a Controller to a ControllerBase the Index method below throws an error "Compiler Error CS0103", The name 'identifier' does not exist in the current context,

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
    return View();
    }
```

Comment: I'm curious to understand how this is an attempt to answer the question?

Comment: it's one of the things that's different between a Controller and a Controller base. It answers the question directly. It's why they are not interchangeable. The question is not back and white like most people think. Thanks for asking

Comment: Still it's not a full-fledged answer to the original question, it just adds a bit more information, so it's likely better suited as a comment

Comment: Jimbo check it out, if you want to return a view from an IActionResult you can't do it with ControllerBase but you can with a Controller. This is a common method in Core. It's one difference that answers the question