# Redirection to controller from page model not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I learnt that in order for the rules defined for the form fields in a razor page model to work, then you need to add a razor page that contains the definitions for JavaScript files that check user input and validate them against the model rules. Now my model contains an OnPost method that redirects to the controller route if user input satisfies the model requirements. The controller class contains a single action method called PostAction which takes the email and password fields entered in the form as parameters and returns an Ok response if the routing is successful but I am getting request matched multiple end points error. How do I modify my controller definitions and attributes to make this work.

```
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The password field cannot be empty")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage ="Password needs to be at least 8 characters long",MinimumLength =8)]
        [RegularExpression("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).+$", ErrorMessage ="password needs to have both upper and lower case letters")]
        [BindProperty]
        public string? Password { get; set; }
        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }
            //maybe you want to hash the password
            //here is where I am trying to redirect to the action method in the controller
            return RedirectToAction("PostAction", new {Email, Password}); ;
        }
```

This is how my controller class looks like.

```
[Route("api/controller", Name = "Form")]
[ApiController]
    public class FormController : Controller
    {
            [HttpPost("{Email,Password}")]
            public IActionResult PostAction([FromForm] string Email, [FromForm] string Password)
            {
                return Ok(Email + Password);
            }
    }
```

Why is the routing failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your controller is api controller, it like below:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET: api/<ValuesController>
        //[HttpGet]
        [HttpGet(Name = "aa")]
    public IActionResult PostAction( string Email,  string Password)
    {
        return Ok(Email + Password);
    }
}
```

Note, make sure you add below code in the program.cs:

```
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
       pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

result:
[image]

In the OnPost() you can use

```
return RedirectToRoute("aa", new { Email, Password });
```

or

```
return RedirectToAction("PostAction", "ControllerName",new { Email, Password });
```

**Besides**, Redirection is get request, note in your api controller to use `[HttpGet(Name = "aa")]` not  `[HttpPost("{Email,Password}")]`.

**Update**

> the difference between inheriting from controller base and controller

Controllers in a web API are classes that derive from ControllerBase. The Controller class derives from ControllerBase and adds some members that are only needed to support Views. You can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55239380/why-derive-from-controllerbase-vs-controller-for-asp-net-core-web-api) and [Create web APIs with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)  to know more.

> why on redirect to route we need to use a get

From the below request we know it is a get request, so need to use a get
[image]

> the difference between api/controller and api[controller]

when you use

`api[controller]` -> `https://localhost:7037/api/Values?Email=aa@a.com&Password=jjjjjjjjjjjjj`

and
`api/controller`-> `https://localhost:7037/api/controller?Email=aa@a.com&Password=jjjjjjjjjjjjj`

If you want to use Controller,

you can try below:

In Onpost, use:

```
return RedirectToAction("PostAction", "Home", new { Email, Password });
```

And HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    { 
        public IActionResult PostAction(string Email, string Password)
        {
            return Ok(Email + Password);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Suppose I use the redirection that takes the action name and the controller name and object array, let me see if it will work

Comment: Neither works, perhaps I should remove _FromForm_ attributes from the methods?

Comment: @VibrantWaves  Yes,  try to remove FromForm attributes from the methods.

Comment: Removing didn't work also, why is it failing when I have religiously followed every step in your answer?

Comment: @VibrantWaves  What's the error message do you get ?

Comment: _AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:

/Index
/Index_

Comment: This is the url though _localhost:7002/api/controller?Email=davidson@gmail.com&Password=jjjjAAAAA_

Comment: @VibrantWaves Do you change the `[Route("api/controller", Name = "Form")]` into `[Route("api/[controller]")]` and  change the  `Controller` into`ControllerBase`  ?

Comment: no I did not change it to that, should I ?

Comment: @VibrantWaves  Yes, please try my code above.

Comment: It worked, but you should explain why on redirect to route we need to use a get when the for is using post to submit and the difference between _api/controller_ and _api[controller]_

Comment: Also edit to add more information on the difference between  inheriting from controller base and controller

Comment: My system may need to check some condition and save an error to _TempData_ which cannot be used with ControllerBase. Is there a n alternative

Comment: What if I need to add a second controller for registering users, what would be the new name of the new controller and would I use get?

Comment: @VibrantWaves What do you mean " what would be the new name of the new controller" ? The controller name is upset to you. "would I use get' Do you want use redirect ?

Comment: I have a separate model page for registering users,do I need a new controller or I can just put a method in the original controller and give it a unique route name?

Comment: Like I added an action method called "RegisterUsers" in the same controller and then added a route named "bb"  with http get and then I try to access that route from the register model but it's throwing a multiple end pint exception, do I need to map in the Startup.cs?

Comment: @VibrantWaves " try to access that route from the register model" What's your code like ?

Comment: _RedirectToAction("bb", new {Phone, Email, Password1, PHoneNumber}) ;_

Comment: It's throwing an error that my request matched the action defined in this answer and the new one that I added.

Comment: I even tried redirect to Route but same result

Comment: @VibrantWaves  "Like I added an action method called "RegisterUsers" in the same controller"  Try `RedirectToAction("RegisterUsers","YouControllerName", new {Phone, Email, Password1, PHoneNumber}) ; `

Comment: @VibrantWaves  If your use Controller class and RedirectToAction, no need to add `[HttpGet(Name = "bb")]`

Comment: But the controller does not have a name because the controller definitions are the same as those of the controller in this answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254296/discussion-between-vibrant-waves-and-qing-guo).

Answer (score 0):

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", model);
```

This code work when you are in the same `Controller` when you want redirect to action in another controller you must use this example code:

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName", model);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer let me try it,  should I require the model in the constructor of my controller?

Comment: `I require the model in the constructor of my controller?` Not just add model in your action